# Evaluate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x\sqrt{\cos 2x}} \,\rm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x\sqrt{\cos 2x}} \,\rm{d}x$$

I was thinking to write $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ and then to factor out $\sin^2x$ to try to simplify the expression, but gets me nowhere. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The substitution $u=\sqrt{\cos2x}$ gives $du=-\sin2x/\sqrt{\cos2x}\,dx=-2\sin x\cos x/\sqrt{\cos 2x}\,dx$ so your integrand becomes $-1/(1+u^2)$ which is now easy to integrate.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u^2=\cos(2x)$, then :

$u du=-\sin(2x) dx$

Limit of $u$ varies from $1$ to $0$.

Then as the original integral can also be written as :

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin 2x}{(1+\cos2x)\sqrt{\cos 2x}} \,\rm{d}x$$

We get the integral in variable $u$ as :

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2} \,\rm{d}u$$

$$=\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x\sqrt{\cos 2x}} \,\rm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x\sqrt{2\cos^2 x-1}} \,\rm{d}x\\
&\overset{t=\cos x}=\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2t^2-1}}\,dt\\
&\overset{x=t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2x-1}}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=\sqrt{2x-1}}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy\\
&=\arctan(1)-\arctan(0)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x \sqrt{\cos 2 x}} d x = & \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{d c}{c \sqrt{2 c^2-1}} \text { where } c=\cos x \\
= & \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{1}{2 c^2} d \sqrt{2 c^2-1} \\
= & \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{d \sqrt{2 c^2-1}}{\left(\sqrt{2 c^2-1}\right)^2+1} \\
= & {\left[\tan ^{-1} \sqrt{2 c^2-1}\right]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 } \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$